# Use optional parameter in route

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use same route in 2 scenarios,

1. use route without passing parameter
2. use route with parameter

So, is it possible & how to do it?

Comment: yes,use get method

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
You can optional parameters like this

Route::get('my-method/{param?}', function ($param= null) {
// your code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In Web Php

```
Route::get('find-services/{service_name?}', 'commonController@find_services')->name('find-services');
```

and  handle the parameters in commonController.php

```
public function find_services($service_name = null) {// Do something here}
```

Or Simple **use the get method** and check parameter in Controller

```
public function find_services() {
    $input = Request::all();
    if (isset($input['service_name']) AND ! empty($_GET['service_name'])) {
        // Code
    }
}
```

I hope this one helps and **For More Information** Here => https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters